# cjepg not outputting .jpeg file in directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, image-processing, image-compression, libjpeg-turbo

I'm using libjpeg to convert a .ppm file to a .jpeg. Whenever I run cjpeg however no .jpeg file shows up in my directory. I'm using libjpeg-turbo in ubuntu.

```
cjpeg -quality $((f % 2 ? 90 : 93 )) image_jpeg.ppm &gt; image_jpeg.jpg
```

This is an image of my ubuntu after I execute that line of code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyKnW.png)

I've tried reinstalling libjepg multiple times. I'm unsure of what to do to troubleshoot.